# Limit as $x\to\infty$ using that if $\lim_{x\to\infty} (1+ \frac{1}{f(x)})^{g(x)}=e^t$

Tags: calculus, limits

Using that if $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=+\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{g(x)}{f(x)}=t$ then $\lim_{x\to\infty} (1+ \frac{1}{f(x)})^{g(x)}=e^t$

I want to solve the followin limit: $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \Bigg(\frac{x^2+3}{x^2+1}\Bigg)^{3x^2+x}$$

I have tried to call $f(x)=x^2+3$ and $g(x)=3x^2+x$ and the same with the denominator, and I get: $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \Bigg(1+\frac{1}{x^2+1}\Bigg)^{3x^2+x}=e^3$$ and
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \Bigg(1+\frac{1}{x^2+3}\Bigg)^{3x^2+x}=e^3$$

The initial limit is $e^6$, and this is the closest I have come to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get 
$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} \left(\frac{x^2+3}{x^2+1}\right)^{3x^2+x}
=  \lim_{x\to\infty} \left( 1+\frac{2}{x^2+1}\right)^{3x^2+x}
=\lim_{x\to\infty} \left( 1+\frac{1}{\frac{x^2+1}{2}}\right)^{3x^2+x}$$
So with $f(x)=\frac{x^2+1}{2}$, $g(x)=3x^2+x$, we have 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty, \qquad \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}=6$$ 
So using your given result, we should have 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \left(\frac{x^2+3}{x^2+1}\right)^{3x^2+x}=e^6$$

Comment: Thank you, I made a mistake and it is $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=+\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{g(x)}{f(x)}=t$ then $\lim_{x\to\infty} (1+ \frac{1}{f(x)})^{g(x)}=e^t$. Then the answer is $e^6$, you are right.

Comment: @JohnKeeper I thought something was fishy